# Unable to make socket Accept Non Blocking ruby 2.2

Tags: ruby, multithreading, sockets

I have been searching the whole day for socket accept non blocking. I found recv non blocking but that wouldn't benefit me in anyway. My script first starts a new socket class. It binds to the client with ip 127.0.0.1 and port 6112. Then it starts multi threading. Multi threading takes @sock.accept. << That is blocking. I have then used accept_nonblock. Though, that would throw me the following error:

```
 IO::EWOULDBLOCKWaitReadable : A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately. - accept(2) would block
```

I am using Ruby 2.2.
NOTE: I do not intend to use Rails to solve my problem, or give me a shortcut. I am sticking with pure Ruby 2.2.
Here is my script:

```
require 'socket'
include Socket::Constants
@sock = Socket.new(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)
@sockaddr = Socket.sockaddr_in(6112, '127.0.0.1')
@sock.bind(@sockaddr)
@sock.listen(5)
Thread.new(@sock.accept_nonblock) do |connection|
    @client = Client.new(ip, connection, self)
    @clients.push(@client)
    begin
        while connection
            packet = connection.recv(55555)
            if packet == nil
                DeleteClient(connection)      
            else 
                @toput = "[RECV]: #{packet}"
                puts @toput
            end
        end
    rescue Exception => e
        if e.class != IOError
            line1 = e.backtrace[0].split(".rb").last
            line = line1.split(":")[1]
            @Log.Error(e, e.class, e.backtrace[0].split(".rb").first + ".rb",line)
            puts "#{ e } (#{ e.class })"
        end
    end
def DeleteClient(connection)
    @clients.delete(@client)
    connection.close
end
```

Comment: There's a pure Ruby - no Rack - http and websocket server in the [Plezi Framework's code](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi/tree/master/lib/plezi). Look at the code for the Base (core) and Server aspects of the framework. It's a pure ruby framework with no dependancies, so the code could serve as a reasonable example for event handling, multithreading, socket connections etc'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/Socket.html#method-i-accept_nonblock

`accept_nonblock` raises an exception when it can't immediately accept a connection. You are expected to rescue this exception and then `IO.select` the socket.

```
begin # emulate blocking accept
  client_socket, client_addrinfo = socket.accept_nonblock
rescue IO::WaitReadable, Errno::EINTR
  IO.select([socket])
  retry
end
```

A patch has [recently been accepted](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10532) which will add an `exception: false` option to `accept_nonblock`, which will allow you to use it without using exceptions for flow control. I don't know that it's shipped yet, though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going on a limb here, and posting a large chunk of code.

I hope it will answer both your question and the any related questions others reading this answer might raise.

I'm sorry if I went overboard, I just thought it was almost all relevant.

Issues like looping through an event stack, using `IO.select` to push events in a non-block manner and other performance issues are all related (in my opinion) to the nonblocking concept of socket programming.

So i'm posting a ruby module which acts as a server with a reactor, using a limited number of threads, rather than thousands of threads, each per connection (12 threads will give you better performance than a hundred). The reactor utilizes the `IO.select` method with a timeout once all it's active events are handled.

The module can set up multiple listening sockets which use `#accept_nonblock`, and they all currently act as an echo server.

It's basically the same code I used for the [Plezi framework's](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi) core... with some stripped down functionality.

The following is a thread-pool with 12 working threads + the main thread (which will sleep and wait for the `"TERM"` signal)...

...And it's an example of an accept_nonblock with exception handling and a thread pool.

It's a simple socket echo server, test it as a remote client using telnet:

```
> telnet localhost 3000
Hi!
 # => Hi!
bye
 #=> will disconnect
```

here's the code - Good Luck!!!

```
require 'socket'
module SmallServer

    module_function

    ####
    # Replace this method with your actual server logic.
    #
    # this code will be called when a socket recieves data.
    #
    # For now, we will just echo.
    def got_data io, io_params
        begin
            got = io.recv_nonblock( 1048576 ) # with maximum number of bytes to read at a time...
            puts "echoing: #{got}"
            if got.match /^(exit|bye|q)\R/
                puts 'closing connection.'
                io.puts "bye bye!"
                remove_connection io
            else
                io.puts "echoing: #{got}"
            end
        rescue => e
            # should also log error
            remove_connection io
        end
    end

    #########
    # main loop and activation code
    #
    # This will create a thread pool and set them running.

    def start
        # prepare threads
        exit_flag = false
        max_threads = 12
        threads = []
        thread_cycle = Proc.new do
            io_review rescue false
            true while fire_event
        end
        (max_threads).times {  Thread.new { thread_cycle.call until exit_flag }  }      

        # set signal tarps
        trap('INT'){ exit_flag = true; raise "close!" }
        trap('TERM'){ exit_flag = true; raise "close!" }
        puts "Services running. Press ^C to stop"
        # sleep until trap raises exception (cycling might cause the main thread to loose signals that might be caught inside rescue clauses)
        (sleep unless SERVICES.empty?) rescue true
        # start shutdown.
        exit_flag = true
        # set fallback tarps
        trap('INT'){ puts 'Forced exit.'; Kernel.exit }
        trap('TERM'){ puts 'Forced exit.'; Kernel.exit }
        puts 'Started shutdown process. Press ^C to force quit.'
        # shut down listening sockets
        stop_services
        # disconnect active connections
        stop_connections
        # cycle down threads
        puts "Waiting for workers to cycle down"
        threads.each {|t| t.join if t.alive?}

        # rundown any active events
        thread_cycle.call
    end


    #######################
    ## Events (Callbacks) / Multi-tasking Platform

    EVENTS = []
    E_LOCKER = Mutex.new

    # returns true if there are any unhandled events
    def events?
        E_LOCKER.synchronize {!EVENTS.empty?}
    end

    # pushes an event to the event's stack
    # if a block is passed along, it will be used as a callback: the block will be called with the values returned by the handler's `call` method.
    def push_event handler, *args, &block
        if block
            E_LOCKER.synchronize {EVENTS << [(Proc.new {|a| push_event block, handler.call(*a)} ), args]}
        else
            E_LOCKER.synchronize {EVENTS << [handler, args]}
        end
    end

    # Runs the block asynchronously by pushing it as an event to the event's stack
    #
    def run_async *args, &block
        E_LOCKER.synchronize {EVENTS << [ block, args ]} if block
        !block.nil?
    end

    # creates an asynchronous call to a method, with an optional callback (shortcut)
    def callback object, method, *args, &block
        push_event object.method(method), *args, &block
    end

    # event handling FIFO
    def fire_event
        event = E_LOCKER.synchronize {EVENTS.shift}
        return false unless event
        begin
            event[0].call(*event[1])
        rescue OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError => e
            puts "SSL Bump - SSL Certificate refused?"
        rescue Exception => e
            raise if e.is_a?(SignalException) || e.is_a?(SystemExit)
            error e
        end
        true
    end


    #####
    # Reactor
    #
    # IO review code will review the connections and sockets
    # it will accept new connections and react to socket input

    IO_LOCKER = Mutex.new
    def io_review
        IO_LOCKER.synchronize do
            return false unless EVENTS.empty?
            united = SERVICES.keys + IO_CONNECTION_DIC.keys
            return false if united.empty?
            io_r = (IO.select(united, nil, united, 0.1) )
            if io_r
                io_r[0].each do |io|
                    if SERVICES[io]
                        begin
                            callback self, :add_connection, io.accept_nonblock, SERVICES[io]
                        rescue Errno::EWOULDBLOCK => e

                        rescue => e
                            # log
                        end
                    elsif IO_CONNECTION_DIC[io]
                        callback(self, :got_data, io, IO_CONNECTION_DIC[io] )
                    else
                        puts "what?!"
                        remove_connection(io)
                        SERVICES.delete(io)
                    end
                end
                io_r[2].each { |io| (remove_connection(io) || SERVICES.delete(io)).close rescue true }
            end
        end
        callback self, :clear_connections
        true
    end

    #######################
    # IO - listening sockets (services)
    SERVICES = {}
    S_LOCKER = Mutex.new

    def add_service port = 3000, parameters = {}
        parameters[:port] ||= port
        parameters.update port if port.is_a?(Hash)
        service = TCPServer.new(parameters[:port])
        S_LOCKER.synchronize {SERVICES[service] = parameters}
        callback Kernel, :puts, "Started listening on port #{port}."
        true
    end

    def stop_services
        puts 'Stopping services'
        S_LOCKER.synchronize {SERVICES.each {|s, p| (s.close rescue true); puts "Stoped listening on port #{p[:port]}"}; SERVICES.clear }
    end


    #####################
    # IO - Active connections handling

    IO_CONNECTION_DIC = {}
    C_LOCKER = Mutex.new

    def stop_connections
        C_LOCKER.synchronize {IO_CONNECTION_DIC.each {|io, params| io.close rescue true} ; IO_CONNECTION_DIC.clear}
    end

    def add_connection io, more_data
        C_LOCKER.synchronize {IO_CONNECTION_DIC[io] = more_data} if io
    end

    def remove_connection io
        C_LOCKER.synchronize { IO_CONNECTION_DIC.delete io; io.close rescue true }
    end

    # clears closed connections from the stack
    def clear_connections
        C_LOCKER.synchronize { IO_CONNECTION_DIC.delete_if {|c| c.closed? } }
    end 

end
```

start the echo server in `irb` with:

```
SmallServer.add_service(3000) ; SmallServer.start
```