# TCP server not showing on local network

Tags: ruby, tcpserver

I have been trying to start a Ruby TCP server. For some reason I can't connect to it from other computers on the same network.

I enabled the Ruby interpreter in my firewall and turned off the firewall. Neither worked.

This works on the same machine.

I'm running Windows 8, without port forward.

```
require 'socket'


server = TCPServer.new 2000

puts 'server started'

loop do

  Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|

    puts 'got client'

    client.puts "Hello !"

    client.puts "Time is #{Time.now}"

    client.close

  end

end
```

Comment: Can you access the server on your own system? Did you try different ports? some ports might be blocked by your firewall...    P.S. a multithreaded server like this could run thousands of threads (1 per connection), which would be inefficient. I recommend trying an [event/IO reactor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858113/unable-to-make-socket-accept-non-blocking-ruby-2-2/29861568#29861568)

Comment: yes, i can access it on my own machine. and efficiency will be dealt with once i get it to work on my network. i tried a few different ports

Comment: Can you give more info about your setup? It might be any number of things: your machine's firewall (not the network's firewall); your router (some networks don't let computers "talk" to each other for safety reasons); the routing/DNS...

Comment: running standart windows firewall, im not sure about my router but i do know i do not have port forwarding thats for sure

Comment: I don't have windows, sorry I can't check on that. Try turning your firewall off to see if it's the firewall. Also, it would be a good idea to check on different networks and review the way you access your computer from a different computer? I assume you use telnet? - Add the info to the question, so people can help you.

Comment: i tried to turn off firewall, did nothing. i assume its my routers fault. and i dont use telnet.

Comment: What's you client? you can't be using a browser, your server is not an http server.

Comment: I assume it's on the phone, not a simulation. Can you connect to other services on your computer - such as a web server?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When writing your question, please take the time to use proper grammar, such as capitalization and punctuation. If you make your question difficult to read/parse, you discourage others from helping you, and you're begging to get down votes. As is, it looks like your shift and period keys only work when you write code.

Comment: sorry, i didnt quite get how to use this thing, im new to the site and i dont care about votes i just wanna solve my problem

Comment: If your server has multiple different IP addresses assigned to it, try connecting to each one.  If you're on the same windows box, can you connect to localhost:2000 ?